# Display all the parents till the top most in comma separated string

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL server table (we use SQL server 2017), Org_Relationship, which has just two columns OrgId and ParentOrgId. The ParentOrgId column holds the Parent org id value of any given org as long as it's available. I need to display the Hierarchy of all the orgs in a comma separated concatenated string starting with the immediate parent and going all the way to the ultimate parent.

There are many similar articles on stack overflow discussing similar topics but I was unable to find a solution that matches my needs. I could be overlooking solutions already provided for similar issues as I am new to SQL Server.

Given below is the create script and some sample data :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[OrgHiearchy](
    [OrgId] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [ParentOrgID] [nvarchar](50) NULL
)
```

[image: Sample Data]

The expected output for say org Ids 100 and 200 is:

[image: Expected Output]

Thank you very much in advance for all the help.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. To solve this you need a recursive cte to get all the data. Then you need to use STUFF with FOR XML to generate the delimited list. I have to run but will check back in a couple hours and see if you figured it out or somebody else posts an answer for you.

Comment: Thank you for your response Sean. I did come across the CTE solutions using STUFF and FOR XML on stack overflow but was unable to implement it myself as I am new to SQL server. I will try my best to do it.

Comment: Don't try to do it all in one step. These are both advanced topics. First get the cte working to get the data. Then work on creating the delimited string.

Comment: Hi Sean. Yes, I was trying all the concepts at once and probably that was the mistake. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, we will build the hierarchies. For this, we will make a recursive CTE called "Hierarchies".

The anchor-part of the CTE will select the "starting points" of the hierarchies. We can make the base query including this anchor query in the CTE like this:

```
WITH
    [Hierarchies] ([BaseId], [Level], [Id]) AS
    (
        SELECT [OrgId], 1, [ParentOrgId]
        FROM [OrgHierarchy]
    )
SELECT *
FROM [Hierarchies]
ORDER BY [BaseId], [Level];
```

which provides the following output:

```
BaseId      Level      Id
100         1          600011944
200         1          1045
1045        1          250013
250013      1          600021987
600011944   1          600011945
```

The `BaseId` field will always contain the Id of the starting point. For each new level in the hierarchy, that `BaseId` field will be duplicated.
The `Level` field will increase for each step, of course.
And the `Id` field will contain the parent id for that specific level.

Thus we can extend the CTE by adding a recursive query (which is separated from the anchor query using a `UNION ALL` operator) like this:

```
WITH
    [Hierarchies] ([BaseId], [Level], [Id]) AS
    (
        SELECT [OrgId], 1, [ParentOrgId]
        FROM [OrgHierarchy]
      UNION ALL
        SELECT [BaseId], [Level] + 1, [ParentOrgId]
        FROM [OrgHierarchy] INNER JOIN [Hierarchies] ON [Id] = [OrgId]
    )
SELECT *
FROM [Hierarchies]
ORDER BY [BaseId], [Level];
```

which provides the following output:

```
BaseId      Level      Id
100         1          600011944
100         2          600011945
200         1          1045
200         2          250013
200         3          600021987
1045        1          250013
1045        2          600021987
250013      1          600021987
600011944   1          600011945
```

This data is structurally fine.
Now we will update the main query below the CTE to "group" the parent ids in a comma-separated value.
We could use a FOR XML query for that purpose, but since we are already recursively walking through the hierarchies, we could also build the CSVs in the CTE.

Let's include an additional field in the CTE called "Hierarchy", being of a long varchar type that can hold all comma-separated parent ids.
The anchor query will just put the first parent id in it. The recursive query will add a comma and the new parent id.

```
WITH
    [Hierarchies] ([BaseId], [Level], [Id], [Hierarchy]) AS
    (
        SELECT [OrgId], 1, [ParentOrgId], CAST([ParentOrgId] AS VARCHAR(MAX))
        FROM [OrgHierarchy]
      UNION ALL
        SELECT [BaseId], [Level] + 1, [ParentOrgId], [Hierarchy] + ', ' + CAST([ParentOrgId] AS VARCHAR(MAX))
        FROM [OrgHierarchy] INNER JOIN [Hierarchies] ON [Id] = [OrgId]
    )
SELECT *
FROM [Hierarchies]
ORDER BY [BaseId], [Level];
```

which provides the following output:

```
BaseId      Level      Id          Hierarchy
100         1          600011944   600011944
100         2          600011945   600011944, 600011945
200         1          1045        1045
200         2          250013      1045, 250013
200         3          600021987   1045, 250013, 600021987
1045        1          250013      250013
1045        2          600021987   250013, 600021987
250013      1          600021987   600021987
600011944   1          600011945   600011945
```

Looks like we're almost there now. We just need to select all final records.
For that, we use a CROSS apply in the main query that combines the original fields in the `OrgHierarchy` table with the last corresponding CTE records.

```
WITH
    [Hierarchies] ([BaseId], [Level], [Id], [Hierarchy]) AS
    (
        SELECT [OrgId], 1, [ParentOrgId], CAST([ParentOrgId] AS VARCHAR(MAX))
        FROM [OrgHierarchy]
      UNION ALL
        SELECT [BaseId], [Level] + 1, [ParentOrgId], [Hierarchy] + ', ' + CAST([ParentOrgId] AS VARCHAR(MAX))
        FROM [OrgHierarchy] INNER JOIN [Hierarchies] ON [Id] = [OrgId]
    )
SELECT [OrgId], [ParentOrgId], [Hierarchy]
FROM
    [OrgHierarchy]
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP (1) [Hierarchy]
                 FROM [Hierarchies]
                 WHERE [BaseId] = [OrgId]
                 ORDER BY [Level] DESC) AS H
```

which provides the following output:

```
OrgId      ParentOrgId      Hierarchy
100        600011944        600011944, 600011945
200        1045             1045, 250013, 600021987
1045       250013           250013, 600021987
250013     600021987        600021987
600011944  600011945        600011945
```

Looks like we're done now. :)

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much for the overwhelming breakup of the solution query. I'm sure, there's a lot to learn about all the constructs used in the end query and way you explained sure makes me want to learn all about them. Appreciate it! All I had to do was run the query as is and it gave me the expected output. Thanks a ton!

Comment: Hey Bart, a quick question. can you please tell me what needs to be modified in the above query if we were to display the OrgId too in the above output. Expected output for OrgID 100 in the above case in the Hierarchy column would be 100, 600011944, 600011945. Any suggestion would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I managed to do it with this syntax - Orgid + ',' + [Hierarchy].

Answer (score 0):

The [Postgres OnLine Journal](https://www.postgresonline.com/journal/) has a solution to your need([The article link](https://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/131-Using-Recursive-Common-table-expressions-to-represent-Tree-structures.html)). I took courage to adapt it to `MS SQL Server`.

```
CREATE TABLE supplyitem(si_id integer PRIMARY KEY, si_parentid integer, si_item varchar(100));

INSERT INTO supplyitem(si_id,si_parentid, si_item)
VALUES (1, NULL, 'Paper'),
(2,1, 'Recycled'),
(3,2, '20 lb'),
(4,2, '40 lb'),
(5,1, 'Non-Recycled'),
(6,5, '20 lb'),
(7,5, '40 lb'),
(8,5, 'Scraps');

WITH supplytree AS
(SELECT si_id, si_item, si_parentid, CAST(si_item As varchar(1000)) As si_item_fullname
FROM supplyitem
WHERE si_parentid IS NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT si.si_id,si.si_item,
    si.si_parentid,
    CAST(sp.si_item_fullname + '->' + si.si_item As varchar(1000)) As si_item_fullname
FROM supplyitem As si
    INNER JOIN supplytree AS sp
        ON (si.si_parentid = sp.si_id)
)
SELECT si_id, si_item_fullname
FROM supplytree
ORDER BY si_item_fullname;
```

The output:

```
si_id   si_item_fullname
1   Paper
5   Paper->Non-Recycled
6   Paper->Non-Recycled->20 lb
7   Paper->Non-Recycled->40 lb
8   Paper->Non-Recycled->Scraps
2   Paper->Recycled
3   Paper->Recycled->20 lb
4   Paper->Recycled->40 lb
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/a2ec6/6/0)

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the effort to put together a query for SQL server based on Postgre. While I've marked a different solution as the answer for this particular issue, I'm sure I will be able to make use of your suggestion for solving similar issues. Thank you once again!

Answer (score 0):

Recursive CTEs can be tricky, but that is what you want here:

```
with cte as (
      select oh.OrgId, oh.ParentOrgId,
             convert(varchar(max), oh.ParentOrgId) as parents,
             oh.ParentOrgId as working, 1 as lev
      from OrgHierarchy oh
      where not exists (select 1 from OrgHierarchy oh2 where oh2.ParentOrgId = oh.OrgId)
      union all
      select cte.OrgId, cte.ParentOrgId,
             concat(parents, ',', convert(varchar(max), oh.ParentOrgId)),
             oh.ParentOrgId, lev + 1
      from cte join
           OrgHierarchy oh
           on oh.OrgId = cte.working
      where lev < 5
      )
select top (1) with ties orgid, parentorgid, parents
from cte
order by row_number() over (partition by orgid order by lev desc);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=000110fb51aa910ecb8eb06be56d0c42) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. As I executed the query, I was getting the below error. ''CONCAT' is not a recognized built-in function name.'

Comment: it may have to do with the version of SQL server that is setup in my organization I'd assume. But thank you once again!

Comment: @Rohit . . . You can replace `concat()` with the `+` operator.